# Populate Spinner Based from First Spinner in Android

Tags: android, json, android-spinner, android-json

Friends !! I have two Spinner and Data is coming from JSON. I am able to PARSE data and display into Spinner. In first Spinner There are number of nodes which have number s of Details. So my requirement is to populate Second Spinner Based on Selection of First Spinner .. Please help me

```
@Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
         pDialog.dismiss();
         try {
                // Getting JSON Array from URL
                android = json.getJSONArray(TAG_OS);
                for(int i = 0; i < android.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = android.getJSONObject(i);
                c = c.getJSONObject("LearningStandards");

                // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                String ver = c.getString(TAG_VER);
                /*String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String api = c.getString(TAG_API);*/




                // Adding value HashMap key => value


                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(TAG_VER, ver);
                /*map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_API, api);*/

                oslist.add(map);
                list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);





                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, oslist,
                        R.layout.list_v,
                        new String[] { TAG_VER,TAG_NAME, TAG_API }, new int[] {
                                R.id.vers,R.id.name, R.id.api});

                list.setAdapter(adapter);
                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You Clicked at "+oslist.get(+position).get("ref_id"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

                }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Where is Spinner related code?

Comment: HI thnxx fro your quick response.. actually firstly I populated into  List but now i want to display all data into spinner. I am able to get data into spinner. but i want to make it dependable . if first node is selected then all the data related with that node must be populate into second spinner. Please help me sir..

Comment: Show code by which populating data in Spinner

Comment: use setSelection method of spinner and pass position of dependent value. and please provide spinner code as per @ρяσѕρєяK suggest.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK .. PLease let me knoe if you have any idea ..I am not maste in JSON and Parsing so I am learing right now. By seeing exmaple I am able to code. but In this spinner, Main node have to populate in to first and then when user choose them based on that second spinner must b populate.. please help me. I can give you JSON Link

Answer (score 0):

Use: **spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener**

I have created Category and Subcategory spinners. Subcategory values are showed based on Category selection.
Following is the code sample:

```
    spn_category.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                    String selection = spn_category.getSelectedItem().toString();
                ArrayAdapter<String> selection_subcat = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ServiceProviderProfileEdit.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, CategoryInfo.getSubCategories(selection));
                spn_subcategory.setAdapter(selection_subcat);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
                    // your code here (optional)
                }

            });
```

Hope it will help you..!

```
//Answer to your comment:

JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONArray("LearningStandards");
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_standard_title = .... //parse standard_title here
spn_title.setAdapter(adapter_standard_title); //set adapter of standard_titles to spinner
//use setOnItemSelectedListener on spn_title
//in onItemSelected you will receive the clicked category
//you can convert it in string using: 
String selected_title = spn_title.getSelectedItem().toString();
//parse ref_id/other req field based on this selected_title
```

Comment: Thnxx Dsd, what is selection_subcat ?? have you any exmaple sir . please let me knoe, I will learn...

Comment: "selection_subcat" is the adapter name which contains the values to be shown in spinner. I am passing this adapter to spn_subcategory.

Comment: Sir I am giving you JSON link.. I think you can help me very well

Comment: Its contains a lot of nodes, and based on them selected Nodes, Data must be populated into another Spinner..

Comment: I have updated the answer. pls check if helpful. As you know how to parse the data, I have omitted that part and have just suggested the flow.